Number of Observations
I am trying to establish relationship between an organisation’s degree of diversity representation and their annual revenue, and ran into a concern in my data analysis.
If I am looking at the number of disabled people in an organisation, what is my number of observations (N)?. Is it the total number of employees in the organisation or the total number of disabled employees in the organisation?.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
